# Vaadin 10 - Upload Component - remove file event

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

When file is uploaded, a Button is enabled:

```
// myUploadComponent extends Upload
myUploadComponent.addSucceededListener(event -> enabledMyButtonMEthod ()); // working well
```

I don't find out **how to disable that Button when I remove the file** (click on the cross next to it).

There should be something like 'addRemoveListener' ... ?
How can I detect this event ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen to the "file-remove" event in the upload component. Here is an example.

```
@Route("")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() { 
        MyUpload upload = new MyUpload();
        upload.addFileRemoveListener(e -> Notification.show("Button disabled"));
        add(upload);
    }

    class MyUpload extends Upload {
        Registration addFileRemoveListener(ComponentEventListener<FileRemoveEvent> listener) {
            return super.addListener(FileRemoveEvent.class, listener);
        }
    }

    @DomEvent("file-remove")
    public static class FileRemoveEvent extends ComponentEvent<Upload> {
        public FileRemoveEvent(Upload source, boolean fromClient) {
            super(source, fromClient);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have added and event listener like so

```java
upload
  .getElement()
  .addEventListener(
    "file-remove",
    event -> {
      JsonObject eventData = event.getEventData();
      String fileName = eventData.getString("event.detail.file.name");
      // ...
    }).addEventData("event.detail.file.name");
```

Found the solution here: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-upload/issues/347#issuecomment-516292999

Answer (score 0):

I would try `public Registration addChangeListener(Upload.ChangeListener listener)` which should be triggered on the [filename change event](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.1/com/vaadin/ui/Upload.html#addChangeListener-com.vaadin.ui.Upload.ChangeListener-)

Answer (score 0):

I have extended Tulio's solution to get the removed file name as well in the FileRemoveEvent. Comes in very handy!

```
private class MyUpload extends Upload {
    public MyUpload(MultiFileMemoryBuffer buffer) {super(buffer);}

    Registration addFileRemoveListener(ComponentEventListener<FileRemoveEvent> listener) {
        return super.addListener(FileRemoveEvent.class, listener);
    }
}

@DomEvent("file-remove")
public static class FileRemoveEvent extends ComponentEvent<Upload> {
    private String fileName;

    public FileRemoveEvent(Upload source, boolean fromClient, @EventData("event.detail.file.name") JreJsonString fileNameJson) {
        super(source, fromClient);
        fileName = fileNameJson.getString();
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
}
```